# Getting "not a valid month" exception when application deployed on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, plsql

I have an application running on tomcat v7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. In my DAO class i am running an SQL procedure to fetch data to be displayed at front end.

```
        stmtforcase.executeQuery("alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC");
        stmtforcase.executeQuery("alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI");

        CallableStatement cs = connection
                .prepareCall("{ call STATUS_UPDATE(?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
        cs.setString(1, a);
        cs.setString(2, b);
        cs.setString(3, c);
        cs.setString(4, d);
        cs.setString(5, e);

        cs.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

        cs.execute();
```

The procedure code

```
  BEGIN
  SELECT PREVIOUS_LOAD_DT INTO H FROM LOAD_DT_TBL; 
  OPEN AREF FOR SELECT DT,SUM(ACTUAL_B),SUM(PREDICTED_B) FROM STATUS_UPDATE_TBL
  WHERE (TO_DATE(DT,'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE-7,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(H,'DD-MON-YYYY')) 
  AND (TM_NAME=TMNAME OR TMNAME='NULL') AND (PM_NAME=PMNAME OR PMNAME='NULL') AND (VERTICAL=VER OR VER='NULL') AND (ACCOUNT=ACC OR ACC='NULL') AND (PROJECT_NAME=PROJECTNAME OR PROJECTNAME='NULL')
  GROUP BY DT
  ORDER BY DT;
  END ;
```

The **PREVIOUS_LOAD_DT** is a varchar column. This runs perfectly fine when running from eclipse. No errors. But when I export it to WAR and deploy it on Tomcat server, I get a

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

I don't see why this should happen since the oracle database and procedure are the same.
Plus when I do the same in Windows 7 Enterprise, no problems. The deployed version works just as the on on eclipse.

Tried using 11g and 10g with identical tables and procedures. 
Can anybody explain this behavior?

### Edit

Using **SYSDATE** in place of **TO_DATE(SYSDATE-7,'DD-MON-YYYY')** gives the same problem. But hard coding like **TO_DATE('29-OCT-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')** works. I don't see how the calling environment can affect the working of the proc since I am not passing any date values as **IN** params. All date based queries are from within the proc.

Note: I am using varchar for the date columns since using Date type throws errors while loading the date from csv using sql loader.

Comment: have you checked the culture on both your and deployment machine

Comment: I guess the problem is with the `MON` format of the date - once it recognizes the short month name when the sessions parameters are set as you expect, and when you run it as a WAR, the connection created has different sessions parameters and the short name of the month is not recognized. Can you change from `DD-MON-YYYY` to `DD-MM-YYYY`? Or do you actually have short month names in your columns? What is the datatype of `DT` and `H` in your query?

Comment: Use the correct types instead of strings or you will suffer from pain forever.

Comment: I see your point. Please check the edit for a bit more info. **SYSDATE** is in the native 7-bit date format. Why would it give such an error?

Comment: Brij, what exactly do you mean by "culture"?? Environment ??